# How to evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{2-t}{t^2-t+1} dt$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How to evaluate $$\int_0^1 \frac{2-t}{t^2-t+1} dt\;?$$

I tried doing it using $s=-t+1$ but it wasn't useful. We've learned in class that having a polynomial in the denominator is considered to be "good"/"easy". I can't think of a way though.

Comment: If you look carefully my answer in [AoPS](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=296&t=616914) that I cited on your previous OP, you should notice that \begin{align*}\int_0^1\frac{x-2}{x^2-x+1}dx&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{2x-1}{x^2-x+1}dx-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2-x+1}\\&=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^1\frac{d(x^2-x+1)}{x^2-x+1}-\frac{3}{2}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}}\\ \end{align*}

Comment: Thank you @Anastasiya-Romanova秀! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HINT:

As $t^2-t+1=\dfrac{(2t-1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}4$

set $2t-1=\sqrt3\tan\theta$

---

Another way would be:

As $\dfrac{d(t^2-t+1)}{dt}=2t-1$

If $I=\dfrac{2-t}{t^2-t+1} dt,$

$2I=\dfrac{4-2t}{t^2-t+1} dt=\dfrac{3-(2t-1)}{t^2-t+1} dt$

$=3\int\dfrac{dt}{t^2-t+1}-\int\dfrac{(2t-1)dt}{t^2-t+1}$

Finally, $\int\dfrac{dt}{t^2-t+1}=4\int\dfrac{dt}{(2t-1)^2+(\sqrt3)^2}=?$

Comment: How did you come up with that?

Comment: How in the world did you come up with that? O_o

Comment: @AlonAlon, See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_substitution and http://www.sosmath.com/calculus/integration/trigsub/trigsub.html

Comment: @AlonAlon it can be obtained by completing the square: $$t^2 - t + 1 = t^2 - 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)t + \frac{1}{4} + 1 - \frac{1}{4} = \left(t - \frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{4}$$ The last expression can be written $$\frac{(2t - 1)^2 + (\sqrt{3})^2}{4}$$

Comment: @ADG, Why have you copied my other answer into this?

Comment: please make one answer only

Comment: @ADG, That could safely be a request via comment.

Comment: ok, as you wish, I request you now,..

Answer (score 2):

also we can write $$\left(t-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3}{4}$$ and we can set $u=t-\frac{1}{2}$ and we get the integral $-\int \frac{u-\frac{3}{2}}{u^2+\frac{3}{4}}du$ and now we get $$\sqrt{3} \tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{2 u}{\sqrt{3}}\right)-\frac{1}{2} \log \left(4
   u^2+3\right)$$